# Can't load url to WebView

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm getting error as

> (ERROR unknown type 0xb9479ebc (glSizeof,73))

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
WebView wv;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        wv=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        loadWebViewLoad(wv);
    }
    private void loadWebViewLoad(WebView webview) {
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        webview.loadUrl("www.avengerstechnosoft.com");
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you add the network permission into mainifest.xml.
try to add the permission :
android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE